# A confusion on amplifiers

Tags: operational-amplifier

An amplifier normally has a huge gain which outputs the input voltage Vin to an output Vout.
If gain is G then Vout = G*Vin.

But what about in case of a data-acquisition board's amplifier?

Imagine we apply lets say a 5V DC signal to a single-ended data-acquisition board's channel. So in this case Vin is 5V and we expect Vout to be 5V as well. So what is the gain of this amplifier here?

And if the gain is 1 for a data-acquisition amplifier why an amplifier is always needed before sampling the voltage by ADC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the specifics of your data board, but in general an amplifier with a gain of 1 (aka unity gain) is useful for its other properties:

- high input impedance
- low output impedance

These make it a good [buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_amplifier) between various stages so that they don't load each other.

And buffer amplifiers are used as the [first stage of data acquisition boards](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/4494/en/) for this reason.

Comment: so you mean in data-acquisition case the amplifier gain is 1? and is used for buffering not to driver currents from the signals? here is the manual: http://www.mccdaq.com/PDFs/manuals/PCI-DAS6023-25.pdf I just want to be sure if the amplifier in this devices has gain of 1?

Comment: @user16307: Possibly, but I'm not entirely sure. After a brief look at that manual it only mentions the input amplifier on p.30. It doesn't say what gain it has... but the next stage, i.e. the ADC has user-adjustable gain, so the net effect is that you can set the overall gain of the input stage to what you want (well within a range). Also the input impedance is 100Gigohms, which is totally awesome.

Comment: but whats the point to have a gain different than 1 in data acquisition case? if I have 5V input why would I amplify it to lets say 10V? That would be a wrong reading isnt it? Thats why Im confused

Comment: @user16307: Indeed the result would be wrong *if you didn't know the multiplier used*. But you (or rather the board) does know what you set it to, so the software gives the right result by simple arithmetic. That's how you get the four input ranges this board can handle (from the highest being +/-10V to the lowest being +/-50mV); see page 8 in the manual. This allows better resolution on the lower scales (e.g. 50mV) than if you had only one scale. This is not at all different from how a multi-meter with multiple scales works, by the way. This is just the high-end version of the same idea.

Comment: how can I  figure out in which range the gain is 1 or more? for example if I set the range to +-10V does that mean the range is 1? Whats the relation?

Comment: @user16307: The gain is higher on the lower-max ranges, e.g. the 50mV scale would have the highest gain for this example/board. I think you cannot figure out if it's greater than 1 though in general without knowing the intrinsic range of the ADC. The reason for this being that a device could have both amplification and attenuation scales (i.e. gain less than 1). I could be wrong about the impossibility of figuring out the latter on a black box though. Might be worth asking as a separate question so that it gets more eyes.

Comment: I made a new question. Here it is: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/199304/what-is-the-relation-between-the-gain-and-range-of-a-data-acquisition-amplifier