# What is the relation between the gain and range of a data-acquisition amplifier?

Tags: gain

A data-acquisition amplifier has different ranges. The board amplifiers a voltage sample and ADC converts it to a digital code. There is probably a reference voltage inside the board so it compares with it and produces a code.

But how can I figure out in which range the gain is 1 or more? For example if I set the range to +/-10V does that mean the gain is 1? Whats the relation between the gain and the range and why? Lets say I set the range to 1V. Will the gain increase in this case comparing to 10V range? I couldn't figure out the logic here.

Here is the board:
http://www.mccdaq.com/PDFs/manuals/PCI-DAS6023-25.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a 12 bit device used for conversion so, zero to 4095 digital numbers resresent the range from -10V to +10V.

Gain is irrelevant as a concept - if you want more sensitivity such as a convertible range of -50 mV to +50 mV then choose that setting and work with a the same digital number range redefined as the new analogue range of -50 mV to + 50mV.

One thing to watch... your digital number that respresents the analogue value may be 11 bits with the MSB indicating the polarity (- or +) of the signal. This is quite normal but some ADCs use a different numbering system. read the manual!

### ADDITION

There may be gain or there may be attenuation. Consider this: -

If the ADC (at the heart of the circuit) has full scales of +10 V and -10 V then for the +/-50 mV range there has to be a gain of 200 between input signal and ADC. On the other hand (less likely of course), if the ADC's inherent full-scale range is +50 mV and -50 mV then there has to be an attenuation of 200:1 to cope with the +/-10 V range.

Comment: there is a discussion here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/199107/a-confusion-on-amplifiers Do you mean that there is only one gain for this amplifier?

Comment: Forget about gain and concentrate on an analogue input range of "X" mapping to the digital conversion number range of errr.. "Q" or whatever letter you want to call it. It's really a difficult concept to call that "gain" but, in relative terms the +/-50 mV range certainly has 200 times more gain that the +/-10V range. Does that make sense?

Comment: I understand what you mean. You are talking about matching the signal range to daq board's so that we can have optimum resolution. If we map an input of  100mV signal to a +/-10V range, we will loose resolution so we map it to something close to 100mV. So when we adjust this we actually do not change the real amplification of the amplifier. Can we then say the real gain of the amplifier is always same in this case since you say range is irrelevant to amp. gain?

Comment: plus I couldnt still find this board's amplifier's real gain G. Nothing mentioned in manual. Why would it amplify? I guess it is fixed to 1. Do you agree?

Comment: Hopefully, if you read my addition it will make sense (maybe it does already).

Comment: I think I understand now. You wrote "If the ADC (at the heart of the circuit) has full scales of +10 V and -10 V then for the +/-50 mV range there has to be a gain of 200 between input signal and ADC.". Can we say if it is the case, and if the gain is G for +/-10V, then it is 200*G for +/-50 mV range. Can G be 1 for +/-10V?

Comment: For the +/-ten volt range there is no gain stage gain i.e. G = 1 and yes, for the smaller range gain = 200 which happens to be equal to 200*G.

Answer (score 3):

You are fixated on a completely irrelevant concept. There is no way to tell what the internal gain of the board is, and no earthly reason to care.

If your input data range is more than +/- 5 volts, select for a +/- 10 volt range. If your input range is less than +/- 50 mV, select the +/- 50 mV range. Since you have no way to tell the internal signal levels, gain is irrelevant.

Determine your input signal levels and select the appropriate range. Forget about gain.

Comment: i'm curious. cant we say the gain is 1 ?

Comment: Nope. All you can say is the input range. Gain is, by definition, output divided by input. Output is digital rather than analog, and a digital number divided by an analog voltage can be considered various things, but gain is not one of them.

Comment: ok so can we at least say the input signal is not physically amplified? lets say the input is 5V dc at an instant and THE MOMENT ADC samples will it sample the same voltage? in other words will the signal be physically amplified? if not, the gain is 1. isnt it?

Comment: Again, nope. There is no specification as to the internal voltage at the ADC itself, so there is no way to tell what the internal gain is. And why are you so obsessed with unit gain, anyways?

Comment: the thing is if input signal is lets say 1V, and if the gain is unknown; how will the ADC compare the input signal to its reference? why would gain be not 1. why would it be 2 or 3 or 1000?

Comment: @user16307: The gain is not unknown to the DAQ or the people who made it (even if it's unknown to us/users.) See http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/BAB6A8BF6FC6A3C786256CEF000240F1 for example "The gain setting for each channel is chosen and applied when you specify the maximum value and minimum value for the analog input channels.  When you specify a maximum value and minimum value, both the Traditional DAQ and DAQmx drivers will select the best gain setting for you." This is done so that users don't have to think about the gain, they just set a range for the input signal.

Comment: they hide these important details like coca cola formula.

Comment: But it doesn't _matter_ whether you know it or not. All you need to know is that, if the range is +/-10 volts, a 5 volt input will give a 3/4 of full scale reading. And Respawned Fluff is right. Stop trying to do things the hard way.

Comment: It isn't an important detail.  Why would the precise gain make any difference to the user of the device?  What does knowing the gain enable for you?